# CONVERT Time from {yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss} to {yyyy-mm-dd hh}

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to extract data from a large SQL DB on hourly basis. The following query is giving me a grouping on minute basis. I wish to group by the data on hourly basis.

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), t.counterTime, 100) as [Time],
    t.instanceName
from table as t
WHERE t.counterId= @counterId
and t.counterTime >=  @startTime
and t.counterTime <  @endTime
group by t.instanceName, CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), t.counterTime, 100)
```

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms187928.aspx) also does not provide any such option. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, Don't use `varhcar(20)`, use `char(13)` instead.

Comment: Use the expression `CAST(t.counterTime AS DATE)` in your select and group by. How did you come up with this expression?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid casting to date would loose the hour data...

Comment: Oh yeah I missed that bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this,

```
--SQL Server 2012
SELECT FORMAT(t.counterTime, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH') AS [Time]
    ,t.instanceName
FROM TABLE AS t
WHERE t.counterId = @counterId
    AND t.counterTime >= @startTime
    AND t.counterTime < @endTime
GROUP BY t.instanceName
    ,FORMAT(t.counterTime, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH')

--for earlier versions
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(13), t.counterTime, 120) AS [Time]
    ,t.instanceName
FROM TABLE AS t
WHERE t.counterId = @counterId
    AND t.counterTime >= @startTime
    AND t.counterTime < @endTime
GROUP BY t.instanceName
    ,CONVERT(CHAR(13), t.counterTime, 120)

Note: Format would be perfoming slower.
```

Comment: Please note that `Format` would only work for version 2012 or  later.

Comment: Stuff is unnecessary.  `CONVERT(Char(13), t.counterTime, 120)` will return the same string that `FORMAT(t.counterTime, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH')` returns. However I do like the fact that you tested yourself and found Aaron's answer on dba.stackexchage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use substring like this:

```
select substring(field,1,4) + '-'+ substring(field,6,2) +'-'+ substring(field,7,2)+' '+ substring(field,9,2)  from dbo.youtable
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select datepart(hour,t.counterTime) as [Time],
    t.instanceName
from table as t
WHERE t.counterId= @counterId
and t.counterTime >=  @startTime
and t.counterTime <  @endTime
group by t.instanceName, datepart(hour,t.counterTime)
```